# Duas condições no mesmo laço if() javascript

Tags: javascript, html, condição

Não estou conseguindo prevenir o botão `submit` de realizar sua ação caso as informações digitadas não sejam iguais, alguém poderia me ajudar?

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="php/cadastro.php">
    <span class="form_title">Cadastre-se</span>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt_input first_input" placeholder="Nome">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="txt_input" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="email" name="confirmaEmail" class="txt_input" id="confirma-email" placeholder="Confirmar e-mail">
        <input type="password" name="senha" class="txt_input" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
        <input type="password" name="confirmaSenha" class="txt_input" id="confirma-senha" placeholder="Confirmar senha">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="termos">
        <p>Eu concordo com os <span>termos de uso e política de privacidade</span> do WEB TRAINING</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="Cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" class="log_btn" id="cadastro-btn" onclick="valida()">
        <input type="button" name="Voltar" value="Voltar" class="log_btn volta_btn" id="volta-btn" onclick="voltar()">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
   var email = document.getElementById('email');
var confirmaEmail = document.getElementById('confirma-email');

var senha = document.getElementById('senha');
var confirmaSenha = document.getElementById('confirma-senha');

var cadastrar = document.getElementById('cadastro-btn');

    function valida(){

        if(email != confirmaEmail || senha != confirmaSenha){
            cadastrar.preventDefault();
        }

    };
```

*Já está linkado o script no fim do HTML
*Tentei as formas que vocês enviaram, porém nenhuma funcionou

Comment: Faltou o operador (OU) na condição. `if(email != confirmaEmail ||  senha != confirmaSenha){ ...` e para pegar o valor dos campos não esqueça do `.value` ex: `var confirmaSenha = document.getElementById('confirma-senha').value;`

Comment: Note também que você possui um `)` extra no final da função `valida`. A não ser que tenha sido um erro de digitação ao migrar a questão.

Comment: ainda assim não funciona, código corrigido

Comment: Coloquei corrigido em baixo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tinha alguns errors de sintaxe, no `if(...)` e uns `);` a mais depois da função `valida()`, creio ser assim que quer:

```js
function valida(e){

   var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
   var confirmaEmail = document.getElementById('confirma-email').value;

   var senha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
   var confirmaSenha = document.getElementById('confirma-senha').value;

   if (email != confirmaEmail  || senha != confirmaSenha) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }

}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="php/cadastro.php">
            <span class="form_title">Cadastre-se</span>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt_input first_input" placeholder="Nome">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="txt_input" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="email" name="confirmaEmail" class="txt_input" id="confirma-email" placeholder="Confirmar e-mail">
            <input type="password" name="senha" class="txt_input" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
            <input type="password" name="confirmaSenha" class="txt_input" id="confirma-senha" placeholder="Confirmar senha">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" name="termos">
            <p>Eu concordo com os <span>termos de uso e política de privacidade</span> do WEB TRAINING</p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" name="Cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" class="log_btn" id="cadastro-btn" onclick="valida(event)">
            <input type="button" name="Voltar" value="Voltar" class="log_btn volta_btn" id="volta-btn" onclick="voltar()">
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Coloquei o `.value` que me escapou, as outras resposta chamaram-me à atenção para isso. Muito importante também é ir buscar os valores dentro da função senão vai ter os valores errados (os que estão no load da página e não os que estão preenchidos quando tenta submeter o form). Corrigi

Comment: so vou conseguir testar amanha pela manha, mas assim que eu testar aviso :D pelo que vi ele com certeza deve funcionar :3

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: Copiou tudo certinho @MuriloGambôa? Dá algum erro na consola?

Comment: sim @Miguel :3 primeiro fiz por mim mesmo, como não funcionou, eu copiei e colei, mas ainda assim, nada :/

Comment: Aqui está @MuriloGambôa , assim deve ser mais facil: https://jsfiddle.net/rkjswtL7/

Answer (score 7):

Faltou pegar o valor de cada input e especificar o operador que junta as expressões.

Ao fazer `document.getElementById('email');` isso pega o elemento inteiro, no seu caso você deve pegar apenas o valor então especifique a propriedade `value` para cada elemento.

Mude;

```
var email = document.getElementById('email');
```

Para:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

E adicione o operador entre as expressões

```
if (email != confirmaEmail ||  senha != confirmaSenha) {
```

Answer (score 7):

O `.preventDefault()` deve aplicar-se a um evento e não a um elemento. Passa o evento à função e já podes cancelar o evento:

```
onclick="valida(event)"> // no HTML
```

E no JavaScript

```
function valida() {
    if (email.value != confirmaEmail.value || senha.value != confirmaSenha.value) { // <-- faltava um "||" aqui
        cadastrar.preventDefault();
    }
} // <-- tinhas aqui um ")" a mais...
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgyqj33m/1

Nota: tens de usar `.value` para leres a propriedade do elemento. Senão vais estar a comparar elementos do DOM e não o seu valor, como o [@TobyMosque bem referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144107/duas-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-mesmo-la%C3%A7o-if-javascript/144111?noredirect=1#comment298276_144111).

Comment: não sabia que comparar dois `HTMLElement` seria o mesmo de comparar os seus valores: `email != confirmaEmail` e `email.value != confirmaEmail.value`, e muito menos que era possivel chamar o `preventDefault` sobre o `HTMLElement` e não sobre o `Event`

Comment: @TobyMosque haha :) com os outros erros tinha descuidado esse. Corrigi, obrigado :)